# XMPP XEP-0313 Smack Android Get the most recent message for all roster members

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

Once I have a roster I can loop through all members and query with the MamManager 
`mamManager.mostRecentPage(jid, QUERY_META_DATA_PAGE_SIZE)`

However, this only lets me get data for one jid at a time which means if a user has 1000 connections I have to make 1000 network calls.  Is there any way to get the most recent message for multiple jids?

**EDIT**

So I've updated from 4.2.3 to 4.3 of smack to get the latest api and I still can find a way to perform the query I want without looping through the jids

```
for (int i = 0; i < jidList.size(); i++) {
    MamQueryArgs mamQueryArgs = MamQueryArgs.builder()
        .setResultPageSize(1)
        .limitResultsToJid(jidList.get(i))
        .queryLastPage().build();
    MamQuery mamQuery = mamManager.queryArchive(mamQueryArgs);
}
```

So on first login for a new user I'll hit the server 1000 times

**Edit 2**

Actually for first login that query above returns nothing, probably because the local archive is empty so I have to do the following:

```
for (Jid : jidList) {
    MamQuery mamQuery = mamManager.queryMostRecentPage(jid, 1);
}
```

Comment: Using a result page size of '1' appears to be an terrible idea. I would recommend using a higher size like 10.

Comment: Yea I could buffer more for when the user enters a chat from the chat list, but that's not the real issue, the problem is the 1000 queries it makes to the server which takes up to 10 minutes to sync

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly try to achieve, but usually clients just sync the local users archive, which is, if properly done, a single query.

Comment: What query would that be? I'm trying to build a chat connections screen which shows the full roster, and the text of the last message sent, basically like whatsapp, but these rosters could be large, p95 is about 1000 connections in the roster with 65 chats each some chats which are very old and haven't been used in months

Comment: Possibly a query after the id of the message that is on top of the local copy of the archive. Then page until you hit the end of the archive (i.e. the most recent message).

Comment: If a page is 100 messages then that's still 650 queries to the server for the p95 case which is still very slow

Comment: Only for the initial sync, no?

Comment: Correct, the initial sync is the problem

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get the most recent message for multiple jids?

This is a different question then the question in your posts title "Get the most recent message for all roster members", isn't it? But I believe the answer is the same for both questions. Message Archive Management (XEP-0313) queries query an archive. The 'jid' argument only limits the results to only contain messages with that JID.

If you query your local user archive (the common case), then you can query simply the last X messages using Smack with

```
MamQueryArgs mamQueryArgs = MamQueryArgs.builder()
                                .setResultPageSize(<X>)
                                .queryLastPage()
                                .build();
MamQuery mamQuery = mamManager.queryArchive(mamQueryArgs);
```

For more information, look at [`MamManager`'s javadoc](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.3.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/mam/MamManager.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked over the javadoc but it's unclear.  If I setResultPageSize(1) does that mean I'll get 1 message for all jids I'm connected with?

Comment: No, it sets the page size of the results. May I suggest to read about it in XEP-0313?

Comment: So I just read through https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#query and it looks like it's not possible to achieve the query I want without looping like this

for (int i = 0; i < jidList.size(); i++) {
MamQueryArgs mamQueryArgs = MamQueryArgs.builder()
    .setResultPageSize(1)
    .limitResultsToJid(jidList.get(i))
    .queryLastPage().build();
MamQuery mamQuery = mamManager.queryArchive(mamQueryArgs);
}

Which on first login means I have to hit the server 1000 times, seems like a flaw in the design